# How to place the time in the input ="time" in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the code to set to the input type with the `comments mark`.
I am trying to get the input type so I can add a `specific GMT`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function calcTime(city, offset) {

    d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));
    document.write("\n\t\n");
    return "<br>"+"The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString()+ "<br>" ;
}

// get Singapore time
//document.write(calcTime('Singapore', '+8'));
//document.getElementById("tim").value = "(calcTime('Singapore', '+8'))";
//document.write("tim").value = (calcTime('Singapore', '+8'));
// get London time
//document.write("tim".value(calcTime('London', '+1')));
// I TRIES THE CODES ^ BUT IT IS NOT 
document.write(calcTime('Moscow', '+3'));

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="time" name="tim" id="tim" value ="">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.value` with selector. As follow:

```
document.getElementById("tim").value = "22:53:05";
```

**Update:**

Check this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/b05kasba/) demo**

Comment: I added  it like this 
document.getElementById("tim").value = "22:53:05"; but its not yet in the input type

Comment: Make sure you have this script inside `body` and that too within `<script>` tags.

Comment: Okay thanks its now working. But the thing is I can't get the value of Moscow.

Comment: Okay thanks its now working. But the thing is I can't get the value of Moscow.

Comment: The reason is you are giving whole string `5/6/2016, 10:20:31` as value. You need to give only `time` as value.